# how to get element without consuming iterator int rust(problem with rewriting strtol in rust)

Tags: rust, iterator, strtol

I implement `strtol` in Rust like this:

```
fn strtol(chars: &mut Chars<'_>) -> i64 {
    let mut result: i64 = 0;
    loop {
        match chars.next() {
            Some(c) => {
                match c.to_digit(10) {
                    Some(i) => result = result * 10 + i64::from(i),
                    None => break,
                }
            },
            None => break,
        }
    }
    result
}
```

the problem is that after runing `strtol`, the iterator point to the second character after number digit, which should point at the first character after number digit.
For example, if input "1234abc", after calling `strtol`, iterator point to `b` which should be `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fails because you look at `chars.next` to see if it's a valid digit or not then stops if it isn't. This means that the first non-digit will be consumed, as you observed. To fix this, you can pass in a [`Peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html):

```rust
use std::iter::Peekable;

fn strtol<I: Iterator<Item = char>>(chars: &mut Peekable<I>) -> i64 {
    let mut result: i64 = 0;
    loop {
        // first peek the element here
        match chars.peek() {
            Some(c) => match c.to_digit(10) {
                Some(i) => result = result * 10 + i64::from(i),
                None => break,
            },
            None => break,
        }
        // at this point we know it's a digit so we consume it
        chars.next();
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let test = "1234abcd";
    let mut iter = test.chars().peekable();
    println!("{}", strtol(&mut iter)); // 1234
    println!("{}", iter.collect::<String>()); // abcd
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=431ca09b61668831138301ea3d643f1b)

Comment: `Peekable` is exactly what i want. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't, really, because that's not how `Iterator` works.

You could require a [`Peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html), which would let you `peek()` the iterator without consuming the item, but that's about it I think: AFAIK while Rust has `DoubleEndedIterator` that lets you iterate from the back, it doesn't have *bidirectional* iterators (which let you move / adjust the iterator backwards), at least not that I know.

Though I'm not sure why you're taking a `Chars` input either, why not e.g. take an `&str` and have `strtol` return a tuple of the extracted number and the "rest" as a slice? That seems more Rust-ish.

Incidentally your `loop` could be simplified by using `while let`:

```rust
while let Some(c) = chars.next()
    match c.to_digit(10) {
        Some(i) => result = result * 10 + i64::from(i),
        None => break,
    }
}
```

Comment: `Peekable` can solve my problem. Thanks a lot. Also thanks for the 'while let'.
"why not e.g. take an &str and have strtol return a tuple of the extracted number and the "rest" as a slice?" `Slice` is good, but i want to implement a pointer-based function. just personal preference.